# Uploading a file to google docs via a Python script

Tags: python, upload, google-api, google-docs

I'm trying to upload a backup file from my server to my Google storage in a Python script. The backup file is an encrypted zip file (gpg file). It connects successfully, but fails transferring the file which the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "backup.py", line 37, in <module>
    entry = gd_client.Upload(ms, 'Backup.gpg', folder_or_uri=uri)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/gdata/docs/service.py", line 306, in Upload
    folder_or_uri)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/gdata/docs/service.py", line 161, in _UploadFile
    converter=gdata.docs.DocumentListEntryFromString)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/gdata/service.py", line 1236, in Post
    media_source=media_source, converter=converter)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/gdata/service.py", line 1358, in PostOrPut
    'reason': server_response.reason, 'body': result_body}
gdata.service.RequestError: {'status': 400, 'body': 'Invalid request URI', 'reason': 'Bad Request'}
```

Here is my code:

```
import os
import sys
import gdata.docs
import gdata.docs.service
import gdata.docs.client

gd_client = gdata.docs.service.DocsService()
gd_client.ClientLogin('me@myemail.com', 'mypassword')

uri = '%s?convert=false' % gdata.docs.client.DOCLIST_FEED_URI

f = open('backup.zip.gpg')
ms = gdata.MediaSource(file_handle=f, content_type='application/octet-stream', content_length=os.path.getsize(f.name))
entry = gd_client.Upload(ms, 'Backup.gpg', folder_or_uri=uri)
```

It's possible that the file is just too big (56mb), and I can't use Google Docs storage this way. I'd hope for a more explicit error message if this was the case though. I'm wondering if it's a problem with my saying 'convert=false'. It's a Google Apps account that I'm using.

Comment: If you think that the problem is of size being too big, why don't you try to break your zip file into smaller, say 5mb, files and then try to upload them?

Comment: Unfortunately this still produced the same error

Comment: Is this a Google Apps **for Business** account?

Comment: Ah, I had thought it was, but just checked and it's just a standard Google Apps account. That explains it then :( I guess I'll look for an alternative storage solution instead. I was just hoping to take advantage of the 20gig storage space I had there! Feel free to post this as an answer so you get the rep.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uploading files of **any type** are only allowed for Google Apps **for Business** accounts. A regular account cannot upload this filetype. See [this link](https://code.google.com/apis/documents/docs/3.0/developers_guide_python.html#UploadingDocs) from the Google Docs API.

Answer (score 2):

Good news: now Google Apps for **Free** accounts can also upload files of **any type**.

Three key points here:

- Use [resumable upload](http://code.google.com/apis/gdata/docs/resumable_upload.html)
- Append "?convert=false" to the resumable-create-media link
- Upload chunk size should be [multiple of 512 kilobyte](http://code.google.com/apis/documents/docs/3.0/developers_guide_protocol.html#CreatingDocumentOrFileWithMetadataAndContent)

To see an example in python, please go to download gdata-2.0.14 and find resumable_upload_sample.py under the directory samples/docs.